# How can I reuse a SQLAlchemy filter?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a class which interacts with the SQLAlchemy objects through various methods and it issues queries for various tasks. Some of these queries use the same filter for example:

```
def get_all_expired(self,my_model):

    q = session.query(my_model).filter(
        my_model.status == 'OK',
        my_model.is_validated == True,
        my_model.expires_at <= plum_dt.now(),
    )

    return q.all()

def update_all_expired(self,my_model):

    session.query(my_model).filter(
        my_model.status == 'OK',
        my_model.is_validated == True,
        my_model.expires_at <= plum_dt.now(),
    ).update({'status':'EXPIRED'})
```

the query part for these two methods is the same and in my case it is used in other methods as well. I also want to pass different models and get the same queries run on them. Is it possible to create a single re-usable filter so that it is managed in one place and re-used in each query that needs it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so this is not very well documented, in the [official documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.filter) I did not find any examples, or even a mention of the fact that you can unpack multiple filters from a list (maybe they assume it is obvious, who knows).

But the following can be done. Make and unpack a list with the filters, for example:

```
def filters(self):
    return [my_model.status == 'OK', my_model.is_validated == True,  my_model.expires_at <= plum_dt.now()]

def get_all_expired(self,my_model):

    q = session.query(my_model).filter(*self.filters)

    return q.all()

def update_all_expired(self,my_model):

    session.query(my_model).filter(*self.filters).update({'status':'EXPIRED'})
```

I found this from a discussion on a [github ticket](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/discussions/7913) about extending this feature to be able to pass arguments with `or` condition as well (at the moment the list is read in as having `and` logic) and also from [another example here](https://devsheet.com/code-snippet/apply-condition-based-multiple-filters-in-sqlalchemy-query/) (although this one has a mistake on how to unpack lists)

Answer (score -1):

How aboot this?

```
expired_filter = session.query(MyModel).filter(
        MyModel.status == 'OK',
        MyModel.is_validated == True,
        MyModel.expires_at <= plum_dt.now()
    )
    
    def get_all_expired(self):
        return expired_filter.all()
    
    def update_all_expired(self):
        expired_filter.update({'status':'EXPIRED'

})
```

Comment: hello, I wish to just have the filter() object, cause for example the same fitler could be used for multiple models as well for example if instead of having `MyModel` hard coded I could pass different models and I would like to have the same filter for all of them. So I only want to reuse the filter part.

Comment: I updated the question to be closer to what I described

Comment: You can make a function that returns a filter:

def get_filter(model):

    return (model.status == 'OK', model.is_validated == True, model.expires_at <= plum_dt.now())

Then you can use it like this:

q = session.query(my_model).filter(get_filter(my_model))

session.query(my_model).filter(get_filter(my_model)).update({'status':'EXPIRED'})

Comment: I don't see how this could work this method you mention would return a tuple. If you pass that to the filter it doesn't work. If this could work at all we have to have a way to generate a filter but I cannot find how this can be done